# Xuost 13.04 - mouse pointer invisible after upgrade

Tags: mouse, 13.04

I just installed 13.04 and I couldn't help but notice that the mouse pointer is invisible on the desktop. It appears in apps once I manage to launch them with the invisible pointer. Help! 
ps this is a VMWare VM, and I don't THINK that's relevant in this case, but you never know....

PPS I ***am*** able to see the pointer on "Xubuntu Session" and default(which looks to be "Xubuntu Session") desktops. fortunately, I had a bunch of desktops installed. I'm still working on this - I just upgraded - if I come up with a solution, I'll be sure to post. Next, I will try a different login screen(Using gde, presently....)

Comment: I have the same problem. Additional info: The mouse pointer does not appear in several other apps, notably chromium, as long as no mouseover or text input, spotify the same. I think it has to do with a missing/non parseable cursor or possible some user rights.

Answer (score 0):

Tried bunches of things to no avail. Finally did a re-install over the existing system, and, while it reported that it didn't install all the packages, it succeeded and I now have a visible mouse pointer. I haven't noticed any shortcomings yet. But I'm sure if anything is missing, it can be installed....As far as I'm concerned - case closed.